# How to hide the menubar in LibreOffice with the standard toolbar UI?

Tags: libreoffice

***Posted in order to provide the answer.***

[image]

Can the menus (titles of menus with options) be hidden behind one single button?

I see that at least in some of the "User interfaces" (a newer feature that can be enabled as "experimental" under *Tools>Options>Advanced>Enable experimental features* - and then user interfaces can be switched from *View>User interface*) this option is present either as a button or as an option among the "Menu" options.

e.g. with the "Tabbed" UI:

[image]

with the "Groupedbar" UI:

[image]

But I cannot find this with the standard UI, which I prefer.

Answer (score 4):

The button needs to be enabled under *Tools>Customize>Toolbars*.

Search for "Menubar" on the left pane there - and add it to the list  to the right.

[image]

[image]

[image]